# Scikit learn's AttributeError: 'LabelEncoder' object has no attribute 'classes_'?

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn

I am trying to use sklearn LabelEncoder but it say that it has no attribute classes_, but it exists, I don't know what is the problem. Here's a snippet of my code

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
encoder =  LabelEncoder()

def classes_():
                #Return the classes which are classified by this model
                return encoder.classes_
def num_of_classes():
            """
            Return the number of ouput classes
            """
            return len(classes_())

X=TimeDistributed(Dense(output_dim = num_of_classes(),293,activation = "softmax")
```

However, I get this error AttributeError: 'LabelEncoder' object has no attribute 'classes_'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call `fit(...)` or `fit_transform(...)` on your `LabelEncoder` before you try an access `classes_`, or you will get this error.  The attribute is created by fitting.